# Sending reCaptcha token to PHP using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I want to add reCaptcha V3 to a form.

Here is the form:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <!-- This hidden input will contain the token -->
    <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" />
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Now I'm trying to send the `token` value to `mail.php`, So there is a plugin called `jquery.form` I use it to send the Ajax request.

Here is the Javascript/Jquery code:

```
$('form').ajaxForm({

    beforeSubmit: function() {

        //Captcha part
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {

                grecaptcha.execute('My_website_key', {action: 'form'}).then(function(token) {

                    //Set token value to the hidden element
                    $('#token').val(token);

                });

        });//reCaptcha ready    

    },//Before submit function
    success: function(msg) {

        if(msg == 'Message has been sent.'){
            console.log('success!');
        }else{
            console.log(msg);
        }

    },//success function
    complete: function(xhr) {

        console.log(xhr.responseText);  

    }//complete function

});//End Ajax
```

When I submit the form, Then I look at the console, I see that the `token` was empty and it seems that the `success` function is executed, Before the `token` hidden element gets the token.

I can't add the token when the page loads or any other action, Because it expires after 2 minutes, So I need to get a a token and send it to the PHP file.

Comment: 1.Create a new seprate function for captcha creation. 2.Execute it before submitting. 3. Check if $('#token').val(); is not empty, then submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your ajax request in the recaptcha handler because `beforeAjax` will not wait for the its contents to be resolved, change your code as follows:

```js
// Fake grecaptcha method !!! you should delete this
// Form URL was changed as well to satisfy the example
let grecaptcha = {
  ready: function(cb) {
    cb();
  },
  execute: function(key, options) {
    return Promise.resolve('recaptchatoken');
  }
};

let formElem = $('form');

formElem.submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let thisForm = $(this);

  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('My_website_key', {
      action: 'form'
    }).then(function(token) {

      $('#token').val(token);

      thisForm.ajaxSubmit({
        success: function(msg) {

          if (msg == 'Message has been sent.') {
            console.log('success!');
          } else {
            console.log(msg);
          }

        },
        complete: function(xhr) {

          console.log(xhr.responseText);

        }

      });


    });

  });

  return false; // false = prevent submit 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<form action="//reqres.in/api/users" method="POST">
  <!-- This hidden input will contain the token -->
  <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" />
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: I think in this case the form will be submitted, When the recaptcha is ready, Not when user clicks submit, Right?

Comment: it shouldn't, since `ajaxForm` is triggered by the click handler, but let me know if the result its otherwise.

Comment: As I mentioned the token expires after 2 minutes, So if I wait for more than 2 minutes while filling the form, It won't work

Comment: I need to get new one on submitting

Comment: I have updated my code. Upon submitting, we'll prevent the browser from actually submit the form, then we load recaptcha, which will set the token, then we prepare the form (`ajaxForm`) , and then we execute `ajaxSubmit` to submit the form.

Comment: I didn't add the `thisForm.ajaxSubmit(); `, Because I want to keep the user at the same page not `mail.php`, But now the ajax part is not working, Nothing is printed from the ajax function

Comment: any reason why you don't remove the `action` attribute from the form, and use the `url` option from `ajax` ?

Comment: Just added a full example. Good luck.

Comment: Here is how the code looks right now https://jsfiddle.net/uh5jtdgn/ , The ajax part is not working I checked the network tab, If I console logged any thing before it it works, But the code inside the Ajax part is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195266/discussion-between-darklightcode-and-maxwell).